# How to put a watermark at Mapnik tiles?

Tags: style, mapnik

Maybe I have to add new layer with my PNG watermark at XML style, but how? I already tried to change somthing at XML, but don't understand how to add one global layer.

Comment: What did you try? Do you use `carto` as a preprocessor of the Mapnik XML style? Basically you have to end up with a new <Layer> object AND a <Style> object in the Mapnik XML.

Comment: @juminet yes, i use carto as a preprocessor of the Mapnik XML style. Can you show me an example of new layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new features as a new layer in a map made by Mapnik, you have to :

1) Add a new layer in your `project.mll` file (assuming the data is within a shp)

```
    {
      "Datasource": {
        "extent": "-20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34",
        "file": "../path/to/myshapefile.shp",
        "srs": "+proj=lcc +lat_1=51.16666723333333 +lat_2=49.8333339 +lat_0=90 +lon_0=4.367486666666666 +x_0=150000.013 +y_0=5400088.438 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-106.869,52.2978,-103.724,0.3366,-0.457,1.8422,-1.2747 +units=m +no_defs",
        "type": "shape"
      },
      "geometry": "linestring",
      "id": "newlayer",
      "srs": "+proj=lcc +lat_1=51.16666723333333 +lat_2=49.8333339 +lat_0=90 +lon_0=4.367486666666666 +x_0=150000.013 +y_0=5400088.438 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-106.869,52.2978,-103.724,0.3366,-0.457,1.8422,-1.2747 +units=m +no_defs",
      "status": "on"
    },
```

2) Add a new style in your cartoCSS files with the same identifier as in `id`:

```
#newlayer {
    marker-file: url(../img/icon.svg);
}
```

Related doc is here: https://cartocss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mml.html#layer-reference